# Positioning image and text in one line. Text won't center

Tags: html, css, positioning

I want the text to be centered and I tried to move the article container, position it,also I tried to make the text and the image in one line with floating, but it only works when I make the whole section inline-block, the aside inline and the article inline-block. And yes, I've read what I could find in google and stackoverflow. Run the code snippet in full page to see the result

```css
#about-me{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(71.2%, 53.7%, 90.5%);
}
#about-me aside{
    display: inline;
}

#about-me article{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;     
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#about-me h2{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 200%;
} 
#about-me p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 150%;
    
}
```

```html
            <section id="about-me">
                <aside>
                  <img src="http://blog.debugme.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/great-frontend.png" alt="" />
                </aside>
                <article>
                    <h2>Test</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non nihil doloribus molestias perferendis quaerat nam consectetur magni asperiores. Et minus ratione atque delectus adipisci distinctio, mollitia! Repellat illo sunt rerum.</p>
                </article>
          </section>
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT1JY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to vertical center the text with your image. So you can use flexbox to solve this:

```css
#about-me {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(71.2%, 53.7%, 90.5%);
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
#about-me aside {
  display: inline;
}
#about-me article {
  align-self:center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}
#about-me h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 200%;
} 
#about-me p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<section id="about-me">
  <aside>
    <img src="http://blog.debugme.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/great-frontend.png" alt="" />
  </aside>
  <article>
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non nihil doloribus molestias perferendis quaerat nam consectetur magni asperiores. Et minus ratione atque delectus adipisci distinctio, mollitia! Repellat illo sunt rerum.</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `text-align: center;`  to `#about-me`

```css
#about-me{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(71.2%, 53.7%, 90.5%);
    text-align: center;
}
#about-me aside{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

#about-me article{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;     
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#about-me h2{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 200%;
} 
#about-me p{
    font-size: 150%;
    
}
```

```html
<section id="about-me">
                <aside>
                  <img src="http://blog.debugme.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/great-frontend.png" alt="" />
                </aside>
                <article>
                    <h2>Test</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non nihil doloribus molestias perferendis quaerat nam consectetur magni asperiores. Et minus ratione atque delectus adipisci distinctio, mollitia! Repellat illo sunt rerum.</p>
                </article>
          </section>
```

Comment: I tried this. The text is centered, but on the bottom. Maybe I wasn't clear in what I want to do?

Comment: I've changed the answer. Have a look.